# Marionette layout view -- why is a template necessary

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In spite of reading the marionette docs several times over, I am still not able to fully comprehend some aspects of it correctly.

I am creating a layout view 'AppLayout' as below:

```
var AppLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({

    regions: {
        headerRegion: "#ecp_header",
        bodyRegion: "#ecp_layout_region"
    },
    ...
```

The html snippet for my app is having the two dom nodes for above defined regions:

```
    <div id="ecp_header"></div>

    <div class="container" id="ecp_layout_region">
        <div class="row" id="ecp_body">
            ...
```

in app.js, my calling code is like this..

```
ECPApp.on('start', function() {
    require(['controller_cp', 'header_view'], function(ControllerCP, HeaderView) {
        console.log("On start event executing...");

        // create a event aggregator vent object and attach to app.
        ECPApp.vent =  new Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator();

        var appLayoutView = new AppLayoutView();
        appLayoutView.render();
        //appLayoutView.showLayout();

        //$('div.toolbar > ul > li:first > a').tab('show');
        if (Backbone.history) Backbone.history.start();

    });
```

This gives me error **Cannot render the template since it is null or undefined.**

I thought that the default render() behavior of layout always looks for a template, so I rolled out my own version of render, as below:

```
render: function() {
    var $self = this;

    /* if no session exists, show welcome page */
    var promise = ECPApp.request('entities:session');
    promise.done(function(data) {
        if (data.result==0) {
            console.log('Valid session exists. Showing home page...!');
            $self.showHome();
        } else {
            console.log('No session exists. Showing welcome page...!');             
            $self.showWelcome();                    
        }
    }).fail(function(status) {
        console.log('No session exists. Showing welcome page...!');             
        $self.showWelcome();
    });
        return $self;
    },

    showWelcome: function() {
        var self = this;
        require(['header_view', 'welcome_view'], 
                function(HeaderView, WelcomeView) {
            var headerView = new HeaderView();          
            var welcomeView = new WelcomeView();
            self.bodyRegion.show(welcomeView);              
        });
    }
```

This time, I get another error saying, **An "el" #ecp_layout_region must exist in DOM**.  However I am sure that the element is existing in the DOM, as I can see it by checking in the debug console window.  Running $('#ecp_layout_region') shows a valid element.

Marionette layout view is pretty confusing. Going forward I need multiple nested views.  I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

How is your template located? Is your template wrapped by `<script type = “text/template”>` tag?
It may look like this:

Inside your html, in `head` section:

```
<script type = “text/template” id="yourLayout">
   <div id="ecp_header"></div>
   <div class="container" id="ecp_layout_region">...</div>
</script>
```

And in Layout definition:

```
var AppLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: '#yourLayout'
...
});
```

Comment: I have no template for my layout view, as its region element was already present in DOM.  I have templates for the sub-views inside layout view.

I realized that even though I had defined 2 existing div nodes as the regions of my layout views, the layout view itself needed to be added to the html.  

I now created an "el" attribute in my layout, mapping it to body element of html. So now layout has a el: body, and two regions (header, content).  This works fine now.

Comment: Still learning and unlearning marionette. So, .. lots of confusions :)